# Export single database, import to different database, Console only

Tags: google-cloud-sql

In Google Cloud SQL, is there a way to export a single MySQL database (not the entire server) and then import that data into a different existing database on a different Cloud SQL Server, all through the console?

I know that this wouldn't be very difficult to do through the command line, but I'm looking for a Console-only solution. The things I can get to work are:

1. To restore an entire server
2. To restore a single database as a new database in an existing server

but neither of those are what I'm looking to accomplish. I want to overwrite a database in one server with the data from a database in another.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you can do:

1. Go to the first Cloud SQL instance
2. On the top there should be a button saying "*EXPORT*"
3. Select a bucket, and click on "*Show advanced options*".
4. Select the database(s) you want to export
5. Go to the second Cloud SQL instance
6. Click on the "*IMPORT*" button next to "*EXPORT*"
7. Select the file that you exported

I think that's what you want, if it's not, please reply so I can understand better.

Comment: That's very close to what I'd like to do, but I've found that that imports the database as a new database in the target server (even if you specify a target database during import, it still creates a new database under the name from the source). I was hoping that there was a way to overwrite an existing database on the target with the import.

Comment: When you import the file, it runs a series of SQL commands to re-create the Database. 
The exported file has a `CREATE DATABASE` line, where it will create a database of the same name that it was exported as, if it doesn't exist already. 

To prevent the import creating a separate Database, you can either name the databases in each project with the same name, or you can remove the `CREATE DATABASE` line in the SQL dump file, and amend the `USE {dbname}` line to the Database name you have.